# var someArray = ["a", "b", "c"]; someArray.splice(someArray.length - 1, 1, "d") //["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Tags: javascript

Так почему же при someArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"], someArray.splice(someArray.length - 1, 0, "e"), получается someArray["a", "b", "c", "e", "d"], а не someArray["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], как я предполагал...

Comment: Да, действительно, опять попутал с позицией элемента, спасибо.

Comment: С другой стороны, в someArray["a", "b", "c", "d"] someArray[someArray.length - 1] показывает "d", предполагал, что добавление элемента будет после нее...

Comment: splice ставит на указанную позицию, в данном случае 3 (так в документации). А последний элемент массива всегда отображается как length-1.

Comment: заголовок неверен. в результате выполнения `var someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
someArray.splice(someArray.length - 1, 1, 'd')` в `someArray` останется `["a", "b", "d"]` а не `[“a”, “b”, “c”, “d”]`